# How to get second last row from a mysql database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I just made a query to get second last row from database:

Here Is code:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM
   (select Top 2 * from Categories ORDER BY CategoryID DESC)x                     
   ORDER BY CategoryID
```

but this code gives me error syntax error in new version.

In older version this code work fine.

What is problem: I have 10 results in the table, and when I submit this query, it gives me 9 row. But when 9 row delete from table, now I have 8 and 10. But this code gives me 10.

Comment: So, the 'new' version is an entirely different brand of database?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Categories ORDER BY CategoryID  DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

Comment: It will not work when there is only one record. Follow my answer.

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT *  From
(select * from Categories ORDER BY CategoryID DESC LIMIT 2) AS x                    
ORDER BY CategoryID LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you need something like this `SELECT * from Categories ORDER BY CategoryID DESC LIMIT 1, 1`

Answer (score -1):

Try this will help.

```
select max(value)-1 from table name
```