# How to get previous last row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have below mentioned two tables.

Table1

```
ID      ref_id
O-1     rt-1-r
O-2     rx-2-e
```

Table2

```
ref_id     seq     value
rt-1-r     1       10
rt-1-r     2       15
rt-1-r     3       0
rt-1-r     4       18
rx-2-e     12      1
rx-2-e     13      13
rx-2-e     14      21
```

Required Output

```
ID      Value
O-1     0
O-2     13
```

I have tried below mentioned query but it is working for one `ID` when I pass multiple `ID` in `IN` it is not working.

```
select b.ID, a.Value
FROM Table2 a
LEFT JOIN Table1 b ON a.ref_id = b.ref_id 
WHERE a.ID IN ('O-1')
order by a.seq desc limit 1 OFFSET 1;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get second last row from a mysql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451031/how-to-get-second-last-row-from-a-mysql-database)

Comment: @kmoser plainly. No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ref_id ORDER BY seq DESC) rn
    FROM Table2
)

SELECT t1.ID, t2.value
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t2.ref_id = t1.ref_id
WHERE t2.rn = 2;
```

I don't like not using analytic functions for this, but if you had to here is one way:

```sql
SELECT
    t1.ID,
    (SELECT value FROM Table2 t2
     WHERE t2.ref_id = t1.ref_id AND
           t2.seq < (SELECT MAX(s.seq) FROM Table2 s WHERE s.ref_id = t2.ref_id)
     ORDER BY t2.seq DESC LIMIT 1) AS value
FROM Table1 t1;
```

Comment: Getting some error, I think `ROW_NUMBER()` doesn't work in MySQL Version 5.7.18

Comment: Unless your assignment or situation strictly requires you to use the outdated MySQL 5.7, I strongly suggest upgrading to MySQL 8+.

Comment: It requires MySQL 5.7 :(

Comment: @SophiaWilson I have given you an option which should work on MySQL 5.7, but I don't recommend it.